# Difference between the built-in pow() and math.pow() for floats, in Python?

Tags: python, math

Is there a difference in the results returned by Python's built-in `pow(x, y)` (no third argument) and the values returned by `math.pow()`, in the case of two *float* arguments.

I am asking this question because the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.pow) for `math.pow()` implies that `pow(x, y)` (i.e. `x**y`) is essentially the same as `math.pow(x, y)`:

> **math.pow(x, y)**
>
> Return x raised to the power y. Exceptional cases
>   follow Annex ‘F’ of the C99 standard as far as possible. In
>   particular, pow(1.0, x) and pow(x, 0.0) always return 1.0, even when x
>   is a zero or a NaN. If both x and y are finite, x is negative, and y
>   is not an integer then pow(x, y) is undefined, and raises ValueError.
>
> Changed in version 2.6: The outcome of 1**nan and nan**0 was undefined.

Note the last line: the documentation implies that the behavior of `math.pow()` is that of the exponentiation operator `**` (and therefore of `pow(x, y)`).  Is this officially guaranteed?

Background: My goal is to provide an implementation of *both* the built-in `pow()` and of `math.pow()` for numbers with uncertainty *that behaves in the same way* as with regular Python floats (same numerical results, same exceptions, same results for corner cases, etc.). I have [already implemented](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/) something that works quite well, but there are some [corner cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198753/zero-division-error-in-python-uncertainties-package) that need to be handled.

Comment: Probably nothing you don't already know, but here's some folks messing around with it: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t355507-pow-power-function.html

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### Quick Check

From the signatures, we can tell that they are different:

> **pow(x, y[, z])**
>
> **math.pow(x, y)**

Also, trying it in the shell will give you a quick idea:

```
>>> pow is math.pow
False
```

### Testing the differences

Another way to understand the differences in behaviour between the two functions is to test for them:

```
import math
import traceback
import sys

inf = float("inf")
NaN = float("nan")

vals = [inf, NaN, 0.0, 1.0, 2.2, -1.0, -0.0, -2.2, -inf, 1, 0, 2]

tests = set([])

for vala in vals:
  for valb in vals:
    tests.add( (vala, valb) )
    tests.add( (valb, vala) )


for a,b in tests:
  print("math.pow(%f,%f)"%(a,b) )
  try:
    print("    %f "%math.pow(a,b))
  except:
    traceback.print_exc()
  
  print("__builtins__.pow(%f,%f)"%(a,b) )
  try:
    print("    %f "%__builtins__.pow(a,b))
  except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

We can then notice some subtle differences. For example:

```
math.pow(0.000000,-2.200000)
    ValueError: math domain error

__builtins__.pow(0.000000,-2.200000)
    ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power
```

There are other differences, and the test list above is not complete (no long numbers, no complex, etc...), but this will give us a pragmatic list of how the two functions behave differently. I would also recommend extending the above test to check for the type that each function returns. You could probably write something similar that creates a report of the differences between the two functions.

### `math.pow()`

`math.pow()` handles its arguments very differently from the builtin `**` or `pow()`. This comes at the cost of flexibility. Having a look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c7163a7f7cd2/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1781), we can see that the arguments to `math.pow()` are **cast directly to doubles**:

```
static PyObject *
math_pow(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *ox, *oy;
    double r, x, y;
    int odd_y;

    if (! PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "pow", 2, 2, &ox, &oy))
        return NULL;
    x = PyFloat_AsDouble(ox);
    y = PyFloat_AsDouble(oy);
/*...*/
```

The checks are then carried out against the doubles for validity, and then the result is passed to the underlying C math library.

### builtin `pow()`

The built-in `pow()` (same as the `**` operator) on the other hand behaves very differently, it actually uses the Objects's own implementation of the `**` operator, which can be overridden by the end user if need be by replacing a number's `__pow__()`, `__rpow__()` or `__ipow__()`,  method.

For built-in types, it is instructive to study the difference between the power function implemented for two numeric types, for example, [floats](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6a60359556f9/Objects/floatobject.c#l807), [long](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c7163a7f7cd2/Objects/longobject.c#l3599) and [complex](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c7163a7f7cd2/Objects/complexobject.c#l510).

### Overriding the default behaviour

Emulating numeric types is described [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#numeric-types). essentially, if you are creating a new type for numbers with uncertainty, what you will have to do is provide the `__pow__()`, `__rpow__()` and possibly `__ipow__()` methods for your type. This will allow your numbers to be used with the operator:

```
class Uncertain:
  def __init__(self, x, delta=0):
    self.delta = delta
    self.x = x
  def __pow__(self, other):
    return Uncertain(
      self.x**other.x, 
      Uncertain._propagate_power(self, other)
    )
  @staticmethod
  def _propagate_power(A, B):
    return math.sqrt(
      ((B.x*(A.x**(B.x-1)))**2)*A.delta*A.delta +
      (((A.x**B.x)*math.log(B.x))**2)*B.delta*B.delta
    )
```

In order to override `math.pow()` you will have to monkey patch it to support your new type:

```
def new_pow(a,b):
    _a = Uncertain(a)
    _b = Uncertain(b)
    return _a ** _b

math.pow = new_pow
```

Note that for this to work you'll have to wrangle the `Uncertain` class to cope with an `Uncertain` instance as an input to `__init__()`

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for: some hard facts about the difference between `pow(x, y)` and `math.pow(x, y)` for real numbers. However, there is one missing piece: do you know how `__pow()__` is implemented for real numbers? the big question is: does it use the underlying C math library like `math.pow()` does, and does it handle exceptional cases in the same way (including the exceptions it raises)?  I had a quick look at the source of `pow(x, y)` at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6a60359556f9/Objects/floatobject.c#l807, but have not yet been able to conclude.

Comment: `__pow__` does end up  using the underlying math library. It's [in the file you linked](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6a60359556f9/Objects/floatobject.c#l911) on line 911: `ix = pow(iv, iw);`. Considering what you're trying to do, I would actually set up a test suite and run it against the builting `pow()` and `math.pow()` in order to understand their behaviour. I've added a script that will run a battery of tests for this purpose.

Comment: BTW, I had a look at [Uncertainty](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/), and it looks really useful! Also, I'm wondering, do you take into account the underlying precision when doing your uncertainty calculations?

Comment: Thank you for your nice comment. If by "underlying precision" you mean the float precision, then the answer is "sometimes": most uncertainty calculations are done analytically (the formulas are of course evaluated numerically). However, users can also require numerical uncertainty calculations for, say, Fortran functions that cannot accept number with uncertainties; in this case, I do take into account the precision of floating-point numbers (when calculating numerical derivatives).

Answer (score 41):

`math.pow()` implicitly converts its arguments to `float`:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> math.pow(Fraction(1, 3), 2)
0.1111111111111111
>>> math.pow(Decimal(10), -1)
0.1
```

but the built-in `pow` does not:

```
>>> pow(Fraction(1, 3), 2)
Fraction(1, 9)
>>> pow(Decimal(10), -1)
Decimal('0.1')
```

> My goal is to provide an implementation of both the built-in pow() and of math.pow() for numbers with uncertainty

You can overload `pow` and `**` by defining `__pow__` and `__rpow__` methods for your class.

However, you can't overload `math.pow` (without hacks like `math.pow = pow`).  You can make a class usable with `math.pow` by defining a `__float__` conversion, but then you'll lose the uncertainty attached to your numbers.

Comment: Good answer. FWIW, in the CPython source code, the [built-in pow function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c7163a7f7cd2/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1505) calls `PyNumber_Power`, which calls `__pow__` on the object in question. For example, see the [source for float_pow](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9a84cab7ff9d/Objects/floatobject.c#l637). In comparison, the [source for math.pow](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9a84cab7ff9d/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1780) does indeed convert its arguments to floats first thing.

Comment: You might want to add in that `math.pow` is only there because the `math` module reflects the standard C's math library.

Comment: @dan04: Are you implying that besides float conversion the two functions have exactly the same behavior (numerical results, but also exceptions, corner case values, etc.)? This is really what the question is about. :)

Comment: @dan04: PS: brice's answer shows that `math.pow()` and the built-in `pow()` do behave differently with two float arguments.

Answer (score 12):

Python's standard `pow` includes a simple hack that makes `pow(2, 3, 2)` faster than `(2 ** 3) % 2` (of course, you'll only notice that with large numbers).

Another big difference is how the two functions handle different input formats.

```
>>> pow(2, 1+0.5j)
(1.8810842093664877+0.679354250205337j)
>>> math.pow(2, 1+0.5j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

However, I have no idea why anyone would prefer `math.pow` over `pow`.

Comment: Why do you call the optimization of a special case a *simple hack*?

Comment: @Wolf Because that's what optimizations for special cases are, imho. There's certainly value in them, but they're simple and only address a single use case, making them hacks.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Are you addressing the design flaw with unreasonable function overloading? In that case I agree: A name like `powmod` would fit much better.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding %timeit comparison

```
In [1]: def pair_generator(): 
    ...:     yield (random.random()*10, random.random()*10) 
    ...:   

In [2]: %timeit [a**b for a, b in pair_generator()]                                                                    
538 ns ± 1.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit [math.pow(a, b) for a, b in pair_generator()]                                                          
632 ns ± 2.77 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: The conclusion is actually not obvious from these results: in fact, in Python 3.6.2, if you check the Python bytecode for for `5.2**2.2`, you see that the interpreter calculates it and replaces it by a constant (`import dis; dis.dis(5.2**2.2)`). The timing result for `5.2**2.2` therefore does not include the calculation time!

Comment: @EricOLebigot thanks for pointing this out. I edited the post