# Spark withColumn() performing power functions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame df with columns "col1" and "col2". I want to create a third column which uses one of the columns as in an exponent function.

```
df = df.withColumn("col3", 100**(df("col1")))*df("col2")
```

However, this always results in:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'float' and 'Column'

I understand that this is due to the function taking df("col1") as a "Column" instead of the item at that row.

If I perform

```
results = df.map(lambda x : 100**(df("col2"))*df("col2"))
```

this works, but I can't append to my original data frame.

Any thoughts?

This is my first time posting, so I apologize for any formatting problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Spark 1.4 you can use`pow` function as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import pow, col

row = Row("col1", "col2")
df = sc.parallelize([row(1, 2), row(2, 3), row(3, 3)]).toDF()

df.select("*", pow(col("col1"), col("col2")).alias("pow")).show()

## +----+----+----+
## |col1|col2| pow|
## +----+----+----+
## |   1|   2| 1.0|
## |   2|   3| 8.0|
## |   3|   3|27.0|
## +----+----+----+
```

If you use an older version a Python UDF should do the trick:

```
import math
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

my_pow = udf(lambda x, y: math.pow(x, y), DoubleType())
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the accepted answer: one can now do something very similar to what the OP tried to do, i.e., use the `**` operator, or even Python's builtin `pow`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pow as pow_

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, ), (2, ), (3, ), (4, ), (5, ), (6, )], 'n: int')

df = df.withColumn('pyspark_pow', pow_(df['n'], df['n'])) \
       .withColumn('python_pow', pow(df['n'], df['n'])) \
       .withColumn('double_star_operator', df['n'] ** df['n'])

df.show()

    +---+-----------+----------+--------------------+
    |  n|pyspark_pow|python_pow|double_star_operator|
    +---+-----------+----------+--------------------+
    |  1|        1.0|       1.0|                 1.0|
    |  2|        4.0|       4.0|                 4.0|
    |  3|       27.0|      27.0|                27.0|
    |  4|      256.0|     256.0|               256.0|
    |  5|     3125.0|    3125.0|              3125.0|
    |  6|    46656.0|   46656.0|             46656.0|
    +---+-----------+----------+--------------------+
```

As one can see, both PySpark's and Python's `pow` return the same result, as well as the `**` operator. It also works when one of the arguments is a scalar:

```py
df = df.withColumn('pyspark_pow', pow_(2, df['n'])) \
       .withColumn('python_pow', pow(2, df['n'])) \
       .withColumn('double_star_operator', 2 ** df['n'])

df.show()
   
    +---+-----------+----------+--------------------+
    |  n|pyspark_pow|python_pow|double_star_operator|
    +---+-----------+----------+--------------------+
    |  1|        2.0|       2.0|                 2.0|
    |  2|        4.0|       4.0|                 4.0|
    |  3|        8.0|       8.0|                 8.0|
    |  4|       16.0|      16.0|                16.0|
    |  5|       32.0|      32.0|                32.0|
    |  6|       64.0|      64.0|                64.0|
    +---+-----------+----------+--------------------+
```

I believe the reason Python's `pow` now work on PySpark columns, is the fact that `pow` is equivalent to the `**` operator when used with only two arguments (see docs, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)), and the `**` operator uses the objects own implementation of the power operation, if it is defined for the object being operated on (see this SO response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282852)).

Apparently, PySpark's `Column` has the proper definitions for `__pow__` operator (see [source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/column.html) for `Column`).

I am not sure why the `**` operator did not work originally, but I am assuming it is related to the fact that - at the time - `Column` was defined differently.

---

The stack used for testing was Python 3.8.5 and PySpark 3.1.1, but I have seen this behavior for PySpark >= 2.4 as well.