# Difference between Python built-in pow and math pow for large integers

Tags: python, math, largenumber, exponentiation

I find that for large integers, `math.pow()` does not successfully give its integer version.

(I got a buggy [Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) when implemented with `math.pow`).

For instance:

```
>>> a_Size=32
>>> pow(10,a_size) * 1024
102400000000000000000000000000000000
>>> math.pow(10,a_size) * 1024
1.024e+35
>>> int(math.pow(10,a_size) * 1024)
102400000000000005494950097298915328
```

I went with 10 ** a_size with correct results for large integers.

For floats, visit [Difference between the built-in pow() and math.pow() for floats, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282674/difference-between-the-built-in-pow-and-math-pow-for-floats-in-python)

Please explain why this discrepancy is seen for math.pow. It is observed only from 10 power of 23 and higher.

Comment: `pow(float(10), 32) * 1024 -> 1.024e+35`, the answer is in the question you linked to, *math.pow() implicitly converts its arguments to float:*

Comment: `help(math)`  "It provides access to the
mathematical functions defined by the C standard."

Comment: Unlike the built-in ** operator, math.pow() converts both its arguments to type float. **Use ** or the built-in pow() function for computing exact integer powers**. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`math.pow()` always returns a floating-point number, so you are limited by the precision of `float` (almost always an IEEE 754 double precision number).  The built-in `pow()` on the other hand will use Python's arbitrary precision integer arithmetic when called with integer arguments.