# Python source code for math exponent function?

Tags: c, python-2.7, math, cpython

When I do math computation in Python which library are we using. E.g.

```
>>> 2**0.5
1.4142135623730951
```

How can I find the source code that was used?  Is this just the `math.pow()` function? Unfortunately, `inspect.getsource(pow)` returns a kind of error.

Searching on Github narrows it down to [13](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?p=2&q=math.pow&unscoped_q=math.pow) possible files.  And I don't fully understand how cPython is constructed.

```
/*[clinic input]
math.pow
    x: double
    y: double
    /
Return x**y (x to the power of y).
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
math_pow_impl(PyObject *module, double x, double y)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=fff93e65abccd6b0 input=c26f1f6075088bfd]*/
{
    double r;
    int odd_y;

    /* deal directly with IEEE specials, to cope with problems on various
       platforms whose semantics don't exactly match C99 */
    r = 0.; /* silence compiler warning */
    if (!Py_IS_FINITE(x) || !Py_IS_FINITE(y)) {
        errno = 0;
        if (Py_IS_NAN(x))
            r = y == 0. ? 1. : x; /* NaN**0 = 1 */
        else if (Py_IS_NAN(y))
            r = x == 1. ? 1. : y; /* 1**NaN = 1 */
        else if (Py_IS_INFINITY(x)) {
            odd_y = Py_IS_FINITE(y) && fmod(fabs(y), 2.0) == 1.0;
            if (y > 0.)
                r = odd_y ? x : fabs(x);
            else if (y == 0.)
                r = 1.;
            else /* y < 0. */
                r = odd_y ? copysign(0., x) : 0.;
        }
        else if (Py_IS_INFINITY(y)) {
            if (fabs(x) == 1.0)
                r = 1.;
            else if (y > 0. && fabs(x) > 1.0)
                r = y;
            else if (y < 0. && fabs(x) < 1.0) {
                r = -y; /* result is +inf */
                if (x == 0.) /* 0**-inf: divide-by-zero */
                    errno = EDOM;
            }
            else
                r = 0.;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* let libm handle finite**finite */
        errno = 0;
        PyFPE_START_PROTECT("in math_pow", return 0);
        r = pow(x, y);
        PyFPE_END_PROTECT(r);
        /* a NaN result should arise only from (-ve)**(finite
           non-integer); in this case we want to raise ValueError. */
        if (!Py_IS_FINITE(r)) {
            if (Py_IS_NAN(r)) {
                errno = EDOM;
            }
            /*
               an infinite result here arises either from:
               (A) (+/-0.)**negative (-> divide-by-zero)
               (B) overflow of x**y with x and y finite
            */
            else if (Py_IS_INFINITY(r)) {
                if (x == 0.)
                    errno = EDOM;
                else
                    errno = ERANGE;
            }
        }
    }

    if (errno && is_error(r))
        return NULL;
    else
        return PyFloat_FromDouble(r);
}
```

Is this the code that's being used when I find square root of 2 in Python `2**0.5` ?

---

Looking around it seems that `**` is the same as `pow()` and we can look for the `__pow__()` method in the source code:

- [search results for `__pow__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=__pow__&unscoped_q=__pow__)
- [Difference between the built-in pow() and math.pow() for floats, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282674/difference-between-the-built-in-pow-and-math-pow-for-floats-in-python)
- [`numbers.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5293b4ff2c1b5446947b4986f98ecf5d52432d4/Lib/numbers.py) for How Python thinks of numbers

The consensus seems to be that `pow` is coming from the [`libm`](https://sourceware.org/newlib/libm.html#pow) library.  Possibly like [this one](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/ee19f1de0d0da24114be554fdf94243c0ec6b86c/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_powf.c), `e_powf.c`.  Also there is [`e_pow.c`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/ee19f1de0d0da24114be554fdf94243c0ec6b86c/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c)

```
/* e_powf.c -- float version of e_pow.c.
 * Conversion to float by Ian Lance Taylor, Cygnus Support, ian@cygnus.com.
 */

/*
 * ====================================================
 * Copyright (C) 1993 by Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Developed at SunPro, a Sun Microsystems, Inc. business.
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
 * software is freely granted, provided that this notice
 * is preserved.
 * ====================================================
 */

#include <math.h>
#include <math_private.h>

static const float huge = 1.0e+30, tiny = 1.0e-30;

static const float
bp[] = {1.0, 1.5,},
dp_h[] = { 0.0, 5.84960938e-01,}, /* 0x3f15c000 */
dp_l[] = { 0.0, 1.56322085e-06,}, /* 0x35d1cfdc */
zero    =  0.0,
one =  1.0,
two =  2.0,
two24   =  16777216.0,  /* 0x4b800000 */
    /* poly coefs for (3/2)*(log(x)-2s-2/3*s**3 */
L1  =  6.0000002384e-01, /* 0x3f19999a */
L2  =  4.2857143283e-01, /* 0x3edb6db7 */
L3  =  3.3333334327e-01, /* 0x3eaaaaab */
L4  =  2.7272811532e-01, /* 0x3e8ba305 */
L5  =  2.3066075146e-01, /* 0x3e6c3255 */
L6  =  2.0697501302e-01, /* 0x3e53f142 */
P1   =  1.6666667163e-01, /* 0x3e2aaaab */
P2   = -2.7777778450e-03, /* 0xbb360b61 */
P3   =  6.6137559770e-05, /* 0x388ab355 */
P4   = -1.6533901999e-06, /* 0xb5ddea0e */
P5   =  4.1381369442e-08, /* 0x3331bb4c */
lg2  =  6.9314718246e-01, /* 0x3f317218 */
lg2_h  =  6.93145752e-01, /* 0x3f317200 */
lg2_l  =  1.42860654e-06, /* 0x35bfbe8c */
ovt =  4.2995665694e-08, /* -(128-log2(ovfl+.5ulp)) */
cp    =  9.6179670095e-01, /* 0x3f76384f =2/(3ln2) */
cp_h  =  9.6179199219e-01, /* 0x3f763800 =head of cp */
cp_l  =  4.7017383622e-06, /* 0x369dc3a0 =tail of cp_h */
ivln2    =  1.4426950216e+00, /* 0x3fb8aa3b =1/ln2 */
ivln2_h  =  1.4426879883e+00, /* 0x3fb8aa00 =16b 1/ln2*/
ivln2_l  =  7.0526075433e-06; /* 0x36eca570 =1/ln2 tail*/

float
__ieee754_powf(float x, float y)
{
    float z,ax,z_h,z_l,p_h,p_l;
    float y1,t1,t2,r,s,t,u,v,w;
    int32_t i,j,k,yisint,n;
    int32_t hx,hy,ix,iy,is;

    GET_FLOAT_WORD(hx,x);
    GET_FLOAT_WORD(hy,y);
    ix = hx&0x7fffffff;  iy = hy&0x7fffffff;

    /* y==zero: x**0 = 1 */
    if(iy==0) return one;

    /* x==+-1 */
    if(x == 1.0) return one;
    if(x == -1.0 && isinf(y)) return one;

    /* +-NaN return x+y */
    if(__builtin_expect(ix > 0x7f800000 ||
                iy > 0x7f800000, 0))
        return x+y;

    /* determine if y is an odd int when x < 0
     * yisint = 0   ... y is not an integer
     * yisint = 1   ... y is an odd int
     * yisint = 2   ... y is an even int
     */
    yisint  = 0;
    if(hx<0) {
        if(iy>=0x4b800000) yisint = 2; /* even integer y */
        else if(iy>=0x3f800000) {
        k = (iy>>23)-0x7f;     /* exponent */
        j = iy>>(23-k);
        if((j<<(23-k))==iy) yisint = 2-(j&1);
        }
    }

    /* special value of y */
    if (__builtin_expect(iy==0x7f800000, 0)) {  /* y is +-inf */
        if (ix==0x3f800000)
        return  y - y;  /* inf**+-1 is NaN */
        else if (ix > 0x3f800000)/* (|x|>1)**+-inf = inf,0 */
        return (hy>=0)? y: zero;
        else            /* (|x|<1)**-,+inf = inf,0 */
        return (hy<0)?-y: zero;
    }
    if(iy==0x3f800000) {    /* y is  +-1 */
        if(hy<0) return one/x; else return x;
    }
    if(hy==0x40000000) return x*x; /* y is  2 */
    if(hy==0x3f000000) {    /* y is  0.5 */
        if(__builtin_expect(hx>=0, 1))  /* x >= +0 */
        return __ieee754_sqrtf(x);
    }

    ax   = fabsf(x);
    /* special value of x */
    if(__builtin_expect(ix==0x7f800000||ix==0||ix==0x3f800000, 0)){
        z = ax;         /*x is +-0,+-inf,+-1*/
        if(hy<0) z = one/z; /* z = (1/|x|) */
        if(hx<0) {
        if(((ix-0x3f800000)|yisint)==0) {
            z = (z-z)/(z-z); /* (-1)**non-int is NaN */
        } else if(yisint==1)
            z = -z;     /* (x<0)**odd = -(|x|**odd) */
        }
        return z;
    }

    /* (x<0)**(non-int) is NaN */
    if(__builtin_expect(((((u_int32_t)hx>>31)-1)|yisint)==0, 0))
        return (x-x)/(x-x);

    /* |y| is huge */
    if(__builtin_expect(iy>0x4d000000, 0)) { /* if |y| > 2**27 */
    /* over/underflow if x is not close to one */
        if(ix<0x3f7ffff8) return (hy<0)? huge*huge:tiny*tiny;
        if(ix>0x3f800007) return (hy>0)? huge*huge:tiny*tiny;
    /* now |1-x| is tiny <= 2**-20, suffice to compute
       log(x) by x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4 */
        t = ax-1;       /* t has 20 trailing zeros */
        w = (t*t)*((float)0.5-t*((float)0.333333333333-t*(float)0.25));
        u = ivln2_h*t;  /* ivln2_h has 16 sig. bits */
        v = t*ivln2_l-w*ivln2;
        t1 = u+v;
        GET_FLOAT_WORD(is,t1);
        SET_FLOAT_WORD(t1,is&0xfffff000);
        t2 = v-(t1-u);
    } else {
        float s2,s_h,s_l,t_h,t_l;
        /* Avoid internal underflow for tiny y.  The exact value
           of y does not matter if |y| <= 2**-32.  */
        if (iy < 0x2f800000)
          SET_FLOAT_WORD (y, (hy & 0x80000000) | 0x2f800000);
        n = 0;
    /* take care subnormal number */
        if(ix<0x00800000)
        {ax *= two24; n -= 24; GET_FLOAT_WORD(ix,ax); }
        n  += ((ix)>>23)-0x7f;
        j  = ix&0x007fffff;
    /* determine interval */
        ix = j|0x3f800000;      /* normalize ix */
        if(j<=0x1cc471) k=0;    /* |x|<sqrt(3/2) */
        else if(j<0x5db3d7) k=1;    /* |x|<sqrt(3)   */
        else {k=0;n+=1;ix -= 0x00800000;}
        SET_FLOAT_WORD(ax,ix);

    /* compute s = s_h+s_l = (x-1)/(x+1) or (x-1.5)/(x+1.5) */
        u = ax-bp[k];       /* bp[0]=1.0, bp[1]=1.5 */
        v = one/(ax+bp[k]);
        s = u*v;
        s_h = s;
        GET_FLOAT_WORD(is,s_h);
        SET_FLOAT_WORD(s_h,is&0xfffff000);
    /* t_h=ax+bp[k] High */
        SET_FLOAT_WORD (t_h,
                ((((ix>>1)|0x20000000)+0x00400000+(k<<21))
                 & 0xfffff000));
        t_l = ax - (t_h-bp[k]);
        s_l = v*((u-s_h*t_h)-s_h*t_l);
    /* compute log(ax) */
        s2 = s*s;
        r = s2*s2*(L1+s2*(L2+s2*(L3+s2*(L4+s2*(L5+s2*L6)))));
        r += s_l*(s_h+s);
        s2  = s_h*s_h;
        t_h = (float)3.0+s2+r;
        GET_FLOAT_WORD(is,t_h);
        SET_FLOAT_WORD(t_h,is&0xfffff000);
        t_l = r-((t_h-(float)3.0)-s2);
    /* u+v = s*(1+...) */
        u = s_h*t_h;
        v = s_l*t_h+t_l*s;
    /* 2/(3log2)*(s+...) */
        p_h = u+v;
        GET_FLOAT_WORD(is,p_h);
        SET_FLOAT_WORD(p_h,is&0xfffff000);
        p_l = v-(p_h-u);
        z_h = cp_h*p_h;     /* cp_h+cp_l = 2/(3*log2) */
        z_l = cp_l*p_h+p_l*cp+dp_l[k];
    /* log2(ax) = (s+..)*2/(3*log2) = n + dp_h + z_h + z_l */
        t = (float)n;
        t1 = (((z_h+z_l)+dp_h[k])+t);
        GET_FLOAT_WORD(is,t1);
        SET_FLOAT_WORD(t1,is&0xfffff000);
        t2 = z_l-(((t1-t)-dp_h[k])-z_h);
    }

    s = one; /* s (sign of result -ve**odd) = -1 else = 1 */
    if(((((u_int32_t)hx>>31)-1)|(yisint-1))==0)
        s = -one;   /* (-ve)**(odd int) */

    /* split up y into y1+y2 and compute (y1+y2)*(t1+t2) */
    GET_FLOAT_WORD(is,y);
    SET_FLOAT_WORD(y1,is&0xfffff000);
    p_l = (y-y1)*t1+y*t2;
    p_h = y1*t1;
    z = p_l+p_h;
    GET_FLOAT_WORD(j,z);
    if (__builtin_expect(j>0x43000000, 0))      /* if z > 128 */
        return s*huge*huge;             /* overflow */
    else if (__builtin_expect(j==0x43000000, 0)) {  /* if z == 128 */
        if(p_l+ovt>z-p_h) return s*huge*huge;   /* overflow */
    }
    else if (__builtin_expect((j&0x7fffffff)>0x43160000, 0))/* z <= -150 */
        return s*tiny*tiny;             /* underflow */
    else if (__builtin_expect((u_int32_t) j==0xc3160000, 0)){/* z == -150*/
        if(p_l<=z-p_h) return s*tiny*tiny;      /* underflow */
    }
    /*
     * compute 2**(p_h+p_l)
     */
    i = j&0x7fffffff;
    k = (i>>23)-0x7f;
    n = 0;
    if(i>0x3f000000) {      /* if |z| > 0.5, set n = [z+0.5] */
        n = j+(0x00800000>>(k+1));
        k = ((n&0x7fffffff)>>23)-0x7f;  /* new k for n */
        SET_FLOAT_WORD(t,n&~(0x007fffff>>k));
        n = ((n&0x007fffff)|0x00800000)>>(23-k);
        if(j<0) n = -n;
        p_h -= t;
    }
    t = p_l+p_h;
    GET_FLOAT_WORD(is,t);
    SET_FLOAT_WORD(t,is&0xfffff000);
    u = t*lg2_h;
    v = (p_l-(t-p_h))*lg2+t*lg2_l;
    z = u+v;
    w = v-(z-u);
    t  = z*z;
    t1  = z - t*(P1+t*(P2+t*(P3+t*(P4+t*P5))));
    r  = (z*t1)/(t1-two)-(w+z*w);
    z  = one-(r-z);
    GET_FLOAT_WORD(j,z);
    j += (n<<23);
    if((j>>23)<=0)  /* subnormal output */
      {
        z = __scalbnf (z, n);
        float force_underflow = z * z;
        math_force_eval (force_underflow);
      }
    else SET_FLOAT_WORD(z,j);
    return s*z;
}
strong_alias (__ieee754_powf, __powf_finite)
```

Comment: Before calling this something else has to convert the integer `2` to the double `2.0`, but other than that I expect this is the code that does the real work. And after checking for some special cases, it ends up just calling `pow(x, y)`.

Comment: Python is probably punting to a C math library to compute the basic functions (pow, sin, cos, etc). In old Unix systems, that library was named libm.a or libm.so; I don't know how that stuff is organized these days. Anyway, I think that what you need to search for is "source code for C library math functions" or something like that. It seems likely that the same math library is used for different platforms (Linux, Windows, Mac) but that is not necessarily the case, so that's something else to consider.

Comment: What you could do is to download the complete source and make sure you can compile it. After that, just use your favorite tool to set a breakpoint, or you could glitch the code so that it does something wrong that you can detect.

Comment: The code you're looking for is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3ef769fcd378a7f1cda19c0dfec2e79613d79e48/Objects/floatobject.c#L684). It's separate from the `math.pow` implementation, and differs from it in a couple of details (e.g., handling of overflow). But just like `math.pow`, it [ends up calling](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3ef769fcd378a7f1cda19c0dfec2e79613d79e48/Objects/floatobject.c#L788) the C libm `pow` function for the basis `finite ** finite` case.

Comment: Side note: Don't forget that the Python git repository contains Python 2 and Python 3 sources and HEAD is Python 3. This makes it quite easy to get confused unless you restrict your searches to the respective branches. `**` calls usually `__pow__()` of the left-hand argument. For numbers, if at least one of them is a float, you end up in [`float_pow()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/67b7158d53f33ed644cc11ef394470a859ea8bad/Objects/floatobject.c#L818), which calls libm `pow()`.

Comment: looking here too https://stackoverflow.com/q/5246856/737051

Comment: @dhke I noticed the line `ix = pow(iv, iw);` which is `float_pow` calling on  `pow`

Answer (score 5):

As the comment  `/* let libm handle finite**finite */` in the source suggests, the actual function got outsourced to an external library. The name `libm` is a historic one and is the part of `libc` that does the math. Not everyone had a floating point unit, so not everyone needed a library handling floating point and because memory was expensive in that times it had been packed into a second library. (Yes, it was much more complicated than that, but basically ...)

The code you are searching for is in the source for your `libc`. You may not be able to look into the source of *your* `libc` but the functions in it are standardized and you can take other libraries, like dietlibc, uClibc, newlib (cygwin), glibc and several more. (no links given to avoid link-rot, but a proper search-machine will find them all).

Some of those libraries use the old SunPro code (e.g.: uClibc but also newlib) which is highly optimized, close to metal code but readable and commented, look for the file `e_pow.c` in uClibc or newlib.

If you use Linux you might be tempted to look into the source of your GlibC where one of the many implementations of `pow()`can be found at `sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c`.

Other libraries do it a bit differently although not much, e.g.: dietlibc uses hand-rolled i386 assembler for `log()` and `exp()`.

Comment: FWIW, the code the OP shows isn't the code that implements `2**0.5`. The code that implements `2**0.5` is in `Objects/floatobject.c` in the Python source.

Comment: @MarkDickinson that function uses the native `pow()`, too. Vid.: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L921

Comment: Yep, that's true (and exactly what I already said in a comment on the OP's post :-).  I was merely pointing out that the "let libm handle finite ** finite" comment that you refer to doesn't actually come from the relevant code. (I should know: I [*wrote*](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/cec3f138d8cd6c5e3fd78200119a94d59440cfad) that comment :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ah, no wonder you name sounded vaguely familiar to me ;-) But thanks for your participation here at SO, not all developers do that.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to see/to verify in an experiment. I use valgrind for profiling, but obviously you can choose a tool of your liking.

```
#pow.py
a, b=2, 0.5
for _ in range(10**5):
   a**b
```

and now

```
   valgrind --tool=callgrind python2.7 pow.py
   kcachegrind
```

It is easy to see, that `PyNumber_Power` is called `10^5+1` times and the call-graph looks like following

[image]

kcachegrind tells me also, that the `exp` function is actually from [`w_pow.c`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/math/w_pow.c#L74).

It would help to have a debug-build of python, so it would  be possible to figure out to which function `PyNumber_Power` was dispatched dynamically without much effort:

[image]

This function is, as already figured out, [`float_pow`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L921) from [floatobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c).