# Different results for the same problem solution in node.js and python

Tags: javascript, python, combinatorics, bignum, arbitrary-precision

I solved the following leetCode problem with some code :

---

You have `d` dice, and each die has `f` faces numbered 1, 2, ..., f.

Return the number of possible ways modulo 10^9 + 7 to roll the dice so the sum of the face up numbers equals `t`.

---

I made two versions of the solution code, one in node.js using [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/), and one in python using the math module .

In node.js

```js
const { combinations: comb, bignumber: Big } = require("mathjs");

function dice(d, f, t) {
    if (t > d * f || t < d) return 0;

    var result = Big(0);
    var i = 0;
    var sign = 1;
    var n = t - 1;
    var k = t - d;

    while (k >= 0 && i <= d) {
        result = result.add(
            comb(Big(d), Big(i))
                .times(comb(Big(n), Big(k)))
                .times(sign)
        );

        i++;
        n -= f;
        k -= f;
        sign *= -1;
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(
    dice(30, 30, 500).mod(
        Big(10)
            .pow(9)
            .add(7)
    )
);
```

In python :

```py
import math


def dice(d, f, t):
    if t > d * f or t < d:
        return 0

    result = 0
    i = 0
    sign = 1
    n = t - 1
    k = t - d

    while k >= 0 and i <= d:
        result += math.comb(d, i) * math.comb(n, k) * sign
        i += 1
        n -= f
        k -= f
        sign *= -1

    return result


print(dice(30, 30, 500) % (math.pow(10, 9) + 7))
```

---

Now when i run the code with these parameters : `d`=30  `f`=30 `t`=500 (the last line of each version of the code), i expect the result to be `222616187` .

In the node.js version , that's exactly what i get .

But in the python version , i'm getting `811448245.0` i can't figure out why is that happening .

So why is there a difference in the results ?

Comment: Note that the result of ``dice(30, 30, 500)`` cannot be accurately represented by a 64 bit float. It is off by ``-14999044413600247749080617``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `math` module uses`float`, not arbitrary precision `int`.

> [math - Mathematical functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)
>
> [...]
>
> The following functions are provided by this module. Except when
>   explicitly noted otherwise, all return values are floats.

Since `math.pow` returns a `float`, the leading argument to `%` is converted to a `float` as well.
The result of `dice(30, 30, 500)` is too large to be accurately represented as a `float`. Its `float` representation is off by `-14999044413600247749080617`.

The `**` operator and its function version [`operator.pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.pow) do not force `float` conversion and provide an integer if all parameters are integers.

```
>>> print(dice(30, 30, 500) % (10 ** 9 + 7))
222616187
```

Comment: The [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) builtin also has the desirable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Solved, in a weird way. It turns out, math.pow returns a float instead of int and somehow bugged. I think int % float has a different cast operation in it and treated differently by the compiler. It can be investigated further. If you cast it to int, that would be your answer.

```
import math


def dice(d, f, t):
    if t > d * f or t < d:
        return 0

    result = 0
    i = 0
    sign = 1
    n = t - 1
    k = t - d

    while k >= 0 and i <= d:
        result += math.comb(d, i) * math.comb(n, k) * sign
        i += 1
        n -= f
        k -= f
        sign *= -1

    return result


print(dice(30, 30, 500) % int((math.pow(10, 9) + 7)))
```

Comment: after i saw your answer i got curious and i tried to replace `math.pow(10 , 9)+7` with `10**9 +7` and without casting to an int i got the correct result , how is `**` different than `math.pow` ?

Comment: Math.pow (which is in c) [function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c7163a7f7cd2/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1781)   takes the parameters and convert them into a double(double in c, float in python). Default pow does not do that. This cast operation makes everything different in the background maybe even in the compiler. [Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282674/difference-between-the-built-in-pow-and-math-pow-for-floats-in-python) of default and math.pow here. You can check this out also.