# What is the difference between Python's built-in `pow` function and the `**` operator?

Tags: python, pow

Why does the pow function exists if there is the ** operator?
It's even faster than the function:

```py
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit('pow(3000, 3000)', number=10000))
print(timeit('3000**3000', number=10000))
```

Output:

```
1.3396891819999155
1.3082993840000654
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between the built-in pow() and math.pow() for floats, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282674/difference-between-the-built-in-pow-and-math-pow-for-floats-in-python)

Comment: @hitter no, what I ask is why does it exist because there is a operator which provides the same feature

Comment: Click the link, read the question, and all your doubts will be `casted away in the wind`. ;)

Comment: @hitter - I don't understand. That question is talking about the difference between `pow` and `math.pow` while this asks about `**` and `pow`. Could you gather back your wind-blown doubts long enough to explain the connection?

Comment: @hitter - What makes you think I just read the title? Its a long question and answer, so maybe I missed something, but it simply equates `**` and `pow` and then talks about the difference those two have with `math.pow`. Can you reference a bit of text in that answer that says why `pow` exists so that I can find my mistake?

Comment: As to the original question... there has always been a tension in python among programming styles. Guido [disliked map, filter and reduce](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) because he thought that list comprehensions, etc..., were more clear. `pow` exists because it may be useful to pass it as a function to some other function.

Comment: @hitter - I didn't ask the question and am not responsible for any downvotes. I think its a good question and that the answer is that early in python somebody thought it would be handy to have a functional equivalent to the `**` operator (in the source, both call `PyNumber_Power`) in case someone wanted to pass the function object to some other function.

Comment: @hitter - recall as per your linked question, the `math.pow` function is not equivalent.

Comment: @tdelaney Ok, this is getting tiring. Look, I didn't see your username, and you asked in a condescending tone, that usually questioners have.
I see you are a high rep user. That means a) you are experienced enough to find the answer and b) when and if you find it mark it as a new duplicate, if it's different from what I've marked.

Comment: @tdelaney Also I am not obliged to answer anything, Remember I didn't write an answer, these are all comments ;)

Comment: **NOTE**: We have 2 close votes for a dup, but it clearly is not. Its a good question and one answer is simply that `**` and `pow` are subtly different. Please don't close it unless you find a better quality dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one use for the `pow` function over the `**` operator. First, `**` is really *raise to a power and apply an optional modulus*, as in `a**b % c`. But if you include the `%`, its value can't be `None`. `2**3 % None` is an error. `pow` is really `pow(x, y, z=None)`.

So, if I want to raise a derived value to a power, I could use the operator

```
>>> def powerizer(db, index, modulus=None):
...     x, y = db.get(index)
...     return x**y % modulus
... 
>>> db = {"foo":[9,3]}
>>> powerizer(db, "foo", 10)
9
```

But it fails on the default `None` modulus.

```
>>> powerizer(db, "foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in powerizer
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

`pow` function to the rescue

```
>>> def powerizer(db, index, modulus=None):
...     x, y = db.get(index)
...     return pow(x, y, modulus)
... 
>>> powerizer(db, "foo", 10)
9
>>> powerizer(db, "foo")
729
```